# onclick event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I currently have is

```
<a href="http://tooxclusive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Iyanya-Hold-On.mp3" onclick="a();">
<strong>Iyanya – "Hold On " (Prod. by Don Jazzy)</strong>
</a>  

and the javascript function is 

function a() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        url = "http://www.google.com"
        document.location = url;
    }, 1000);
}
```

The code first downloads the resource and after one-second redirects to the new URL we want.

It is working perfectly on desktop browsers... but not working on mobile browsers... I am unable to find why?. Kindly suggest the solution...

Comment: Please try to use `onmouseup` together with `onclick` and see if it work?
`onclick="a();" onmouseup="a();"`

Comment: No... It still doesn't work...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
function a() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        url = "http://www.google.com"
        window.location = url;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: window.location is the same as document.location